# Changing default port for Jenkins doesn't work (MAC)

Tags: macos, jenkins

**I tried a lot of ways to do it, but no one helped.**

I installed Jenkins with homebrew.
Run it by the command:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
```

I tried:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci httpPort 9999
```

But there is no file 'org.jenkins-ci'. So I created and tried again this command... Restart Jenkins... Didn't help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the **Jenkins** installed by **homebrew** has its options in:

`~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

so you would need to edit that and the relaunch. Note that, if you can't see your `Library` directory inside your `Home` directory in the Finder, you can type `Cmd+Shift+G` and type `~/Library`.

Comment: Yes and after jenkins restart this file is rewritten to its default values